# Do I need Microsoft Visual Studio/Eclipse to code in C++ with libraries such as opencv?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, atom-editor

Basically I am wondering if I need to go through the trouble of using Microsoft Visual Studio or Eclipse for C++ programming in linux and windows. I've found those to be rather bulky, and would appreciate just using a simple text editor like Atom and then compiling it through terminal. The code would of course require open CV packages.

I don't know exactly what I would use for windows, but I'm mostly focusing on Linux for this question.

Thanks

Comment: you can most definitely use a text editor and compile in the terminal using GCC

Comment: Avoiding Visual Studio has always been my strategy and it's working well so far.

Comment: You could probably do it with a row of toggle switches if you have the patience.

Comment: @MarkSetchell **using** VS has always been my strategy and it's working well so far :)

Comment: Why use a car when you *can* walk? Why use a boat when you *can* swim?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not.

MS Visual Studio and Eclipse are just tools that abstract away the building process. In reality, they run the same commands you can run using a simple terminal. You just need to tell your compiler (gcc, for example) where the libraries are and how to link them.

To further simplfy this process, there are build tools, such as Make or CMake (CMake is used by CLion, for example).

Comment: Here the command line the IDE generates for one of my projects: `cl /MP /FR"Release\" /GS- /Zc:rvalueCast /GL /analyze- /W4 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /Ox /Ob2 /Fd"Release\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /GF /WX /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy /Oi /MD /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Ot /Fp"Release\Test BoPs.pch" /diagnostics:classic /std:c++latest` Do you think it is good or bad to abstract that away? :-)

Comment: That's very, very subjective :D. Honestly, I prefer to write up all that stuff in a make/cmake and run it from the terminal.